# Where do I find a database of each city in the world and the languages spoken there? (Ex. Barcelona - Catalan, Spanish vs. Madrid - Spanish)

Tags: data-request, language, city

I'm looking to set up a dropdown of languages once the app picks up the city a person is in. Where would I find this database or API?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [geonames](https://www.geonames.org/) for this. See, for example, Barcelona:

https://www.geonames.org/3128760/barcelona.html

It shows "preferred" names for the languages Catalan and Spanish

[image]

and you'll notice that Madrid doesn't have Catalan as a preferred language

[image]

---

examples of export data: https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

so you'd need the files and `cities500.zip`  and `alternateNamesV2.zip`.

Also check for libraries for Python/R or other programming languages, that download and parse the appropriate language